# I have a question about how to monitor Provider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

Suppose I have a class like this:

```dart
class SampleClass {
  void sampleMethod(WidgetRef ref) {
    final value = ref.watch(sampleProvider);
    print(value);
  }
}
```

In this case, `final value = ref.watch(sampleProvider);` assigns the state to the `value` variable and then `print(value);` is executed. In this case, it is desirable to improve the readability, but I think that the following writing will work without problems.

```dart
class SampleClass {
  void sampleMethod(WidgetRef ref) {
    print(ref.watch(sampleProvider));
  }
}
```

In this case, which is more common, storing the state in a variable before handling it, or using it without storing it in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to store your state in a separate variable if your business logic requires it. If your `sampleProvider` is not an `autoDispose` provider, then its value will be cached whenever it changes. And you can always use it later by simply doing `ref.read(sampleProvider)`.

I should also caution you against the mistake that `ref.watch` should not be used in provider lifecycle methods like `initState` or `dispose`, or in callbacks like your `sampleMethod` method. Use `ref.read` instead.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
To be honest, I don't know what you're talking about, but why can't `ref.read` be used?

Comment: These are the rules for using providers. Refer to documentation -- [Using ref.watch to observe a provider](https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#using-refwatch-to-observe-a-provider)